# CloudPages - Where i upload my files?

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page

at the moment i try to create a CloudPages with "Code View" and not with the "Design View" because i need to create a full width page with a fixed navigation on the left side of the window.

Unfortunately, i do not know where i have to upload my .css and .js files for my html document. I only can create landing pages and i not found a section for uploading any files.

Do any one knows, how that work?

Answer (score 1):

Those files need to go in the [Portfolio](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/portfolio/), which is in the Email application.

[image: Portfolio]